# Can I use Javascript to change div class when div class is not unique?

Tags: javascript, html, css, class

Is there a way through javascript to change the class below assigned to these three different divs. As you can see the class is the same on all but the styling is different and I want to be able to control styling by class:

```
<div class="pending-task-value" style="background-color: rgb(232, 188, 13);"> 0 <!----></div>

<div class="pending-task-value" style="background-color: rgb(47, 145, 211);"> 0 <!----></div>

<div class="pending-task-value" style="background-color: rgb(19, 152, 126);"> 0 <!----></div>
```

Effectively I want the outcome to be:

```
<div class="pending-task-value-total";> 0 <!---></div>
<div class="pending-task-value-phone";> 0 <!---></div>
<div class="pending-task-value-sms";> 0 <!---></div>
```

Edit, here is the HTML in place today... I can't directly edit the HTML so I need a way to change the colors of the background colors.

```
<div class="card-body">
  <div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
    <div class="col-4 pending-task-value-col">
      <div class="pending-task-value" style="background-color: rgb(232, 188, 13);"> 0
        <!---->
      </div>
      <div><i class="fas fa-tasks"></i></div>
      <div>Total Pending</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 pending-task-value-col">
      <div class="pending-task-value" style="background-color: rgb(47, 145, 211);"> 0
        <!---->
      </div>
      <div><i class="fas fa-phone"></i></div>
      <div>Phone</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 pending-task-value-col">
      <div class="pending-task-value" style="background-color: rgb(19, 152, 126);"> 0
        <!---->
      </div>
      <div><i class="fas fa-sms"></i></div>
      <div>SMS</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The only thing that is making each "pending-task-value" unique is the "background-color" style element. I want to change the background-color so that it would be the following below but I need javascript to do it and can't figure out how to make the update:

```
<div class="card-body">
  <div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
    <div class="col-4 pending-task-value-col">
      <div class="pending-task-value" style="background-color: #2B32B2;"> 0
        <!---->
      </div>
      <div><i class="fas fa-tasks"></i></div>
      <div>Total Pending</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 pending-task-value-col">
      <div class="pending-task-value" style="background-color: #1488CC;"> 0
        <!---->
      </div>
      <div><i class="fas fa-phone"></i></div>
      <div>Phone</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 pending-task-value-col">
      <div class="pending-task-value" style="background-color: #d63384;"> 0
        <!---->
      </div>
      <div><i class="fas fa-sms"></i></div>
      <div>SMS</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Or if there is a way to change/add a style to each "pending-task-value" to make them unique so I can then apply css to them would work for me too.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you getting stuck? Can you show us your attempt as a [mre] per [ask]?

Comment: You can have more than one class on an element.  So class="pending-task-value total" might be easier to work with than a single class specific to the total.

Comment: Edited to show current HTML and desired outcome of HTML after javascript.

Comment: You've tagged [tag:css]; is pure CSS styling available to you in this context?

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches depending on whether you know the DOM structure in advance.

If the target `div` is consistently in the same DOM location *i.e.*, the second div within a container, you can target it using the index of the `document.querySelectorAll()` method *vis-a-vis* `document.querySelectorAll('div.pending-task-value')[1].classList.add('pending-task-value-phone')`.

On the other hand, if the order is not known in advance and the only unique property is, in your example, a CSS property, then the `Window.getComputedStyle()` method may solve your use case. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

One way of thinking about this:

1. Get the elements within the container using `document.querySelectorAll()`
2. For each matching element

   - Get the computed style
   - If the unique property value matches a target value, use `Element.classList.add()` to add the desired class name

Comment: So then would it be this:
let para = document.querySelector('div.pending-task-value');
let compStyles = window.getComputedStyle(background-color: rgb(232,188,13);
Element.classList.add(pending-task-value-total);

Answer (score 0):

You probably *shouldn't* do this - the proper way would be to actually edit the underlying HTML or even the CSS to accomplish this. Leveraging this method can amount to loads of extra maintenance work in the future, whereas centralizing your styles in a proper CSS file and decoupling styling from your JavaScript application logic would be much cleaner and easier to maintain.

However, what you *can* do is insert an arbitrary `<style>` block to `document.body` that implements CSS rules using the [`:nth-child()` CSS pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) to accomplish what you seem to be looking for (assuming that the contents within `.card-body .row` appear in the same order each time:

```js
var styleElement = document.createElement('style');
styleElement.innerText = `
.card-body .row .pending-task-value-col:nth-child(1) .pending-task-value {
  background-color: #2B32B2 !important;
}

.card-body .row .pending-task-value-col:nth-child(2) .pending-task-value {
  background-color: #1488CC !important;
}

.card-body .row .pending-task-value-col:nth-child(3) .pending-task-value {
  background-color: #d63384 !important;
}`;
document.body.appendChild(styleElement);
```

```html
<div class="card-body">
  <div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
    <div class="col-4 pending-task-value-col">
      <div class="pending-task-value" style="background-color: rgb(232, 188, 13);"> 0
        <!---->
      </div>
      <div><i class="fas fa-tasks"></i></div>
      <div>Total Pending</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 pending-task-value-col">
      <div class="pending-task-value" style="background-color: rgb(47, 145, 211);"> 0
        <!---->
      </div>
      <div><i class="fas fa-phone"></i></div>
      <div>Phone</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 pending-task-value-col">
      <div class="pending-task-value" style="background-color: rgb(19, 152, 126);"> 0
        <!---->
      </div>
      <div><i class="fas fa-sms"></i></div>
      <div>SMS</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="card-body">
  <div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
    <div class="col-4 pending-task-value-col">
      <div class="pending-task-value" style="background-color: rgb(232, 188, 13);"> 0
        <!---->
      </div>
      <div><i class="fas fa-tasks"></i></div>
      <div>Total Pending</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 pending-task-value-col">
      <div class="pending-task-value" style="background-color: rgb(47, 145, 211);"> 0
        <!---->
      </div>
      <div><i class="fas fa-phone"></i></div>
      <div>Phone</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 pending-task-value-col">
      <div class="pending-task-value" style="background-color: rgb(19, 152, 126);"> 0
        <!---->
      </div>
      <div><i class="fas fa-sms"></i></div>
      <div>SMS</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This did not seem to work or do anything when used, they do all appear in the same order but nothing happened when I applied that code.

Comment: I am able to add CSS styling but for example if I did CSS styling to ".pending-task-value" it would apply that color across all those items which is not what I need to do here. So I really need to like replace ".pending-task-value" with ".pending-task-value-1" and so on so I can style each one independently.

Comment: "*nothing happened when I applied that code*" Can you elaborate on this a bit more? The snippet above clearly overrides the inline styling attributes you've provided.